# bootstrap carousel's indicator background color filling animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an animated carousel indicator that fill its background with the timer on every active `carousel-item`! So here is my code so far but it's not working properly. I couldn't find any similar example!

http://jsfiddle.net/rcf3gv60/4/

Answer (score 1):

update your javascript file to read:

```
var per = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        per++;
        if(per <= 99){
            $('ul.carousel-indicators li.active').css({background: "linear-gradient(to right, red "+per+"%,#C1B7AD "+per+"%,#C1B7AD 100%)"});
        }
        else {
            per = 0;
        }
    }
   , 50);
```

change the value from 100 to 99, and when it reaches 100, have it reset the value of per back to 0.

Comment: Thanks! but there is still a little problem! As you know when the mouse goes over the carousel, the bootstrap timer stops but our indicator continues...

Comment: and another problem! when I go another tab on my browser carousel's interval pauses but the our timer still continues! Is there any other ways to control our custom timer?